# How to call other APK

Tags: android

I Can't execute another apk from mi app.

Found online this way:

```
Intent launch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("<package.name>");
startActivity(launch);
```

But doesn't work.

Any idea to fix it.

Thanks.
Best Regards.

Comment: do u want to launch app or start installation from apk ?

Comment: No I need launch this app when touch a button on my app. In this action I need call another apk installed in my smartphone...

Comment: dude first thing u dont call apk file , u have to get the package name only , first check whether that app is available in your device

Comment: Yeah I know.. I need the package name of the apk. And this app is installed in my device. But when execute the code above my app is broken...

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```